# Canonical way(s) of determining system time in a microcontroller

Tags: embedded, arm, microcontroller, rtos, cortex-m

Every so often I start a bare metal microcontroller project and end up implementing a system time measurement using a random timer unit.

I am working with ARM Cortex-M devices for a (albeit short) while now and typically used the `SysTick` ("System Tick") interrupt to create a 1ms resolution timer. It recently stumbled over a post that suggested chaining two Programmable Interrupt Timers (on a Kinetis KL25Z device) in order to create an interrupt-less 32bit millisecond timer, however sacrificing two `PIT` interrupts which may come in handy later on.

So I was wondering if there are some (sort of) canonical ways to determine the system time on a microcontroller - preferrably for Kinetis KL2xZ devices as I currently work with these, but not necessarily so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical method as you put it is exactly as you have done - using systick. That is the single timer device defined by the Cortex-M architecture; any other timer hardware is external to the core and vendor specific.

Some parts (STM32F2 for example) include 32 bit timer/counter hardware, so you would not need to chain two.

The best approach is to abstract timer services by defining a generic timer API that you implement for all parts you need so that the application layer is identical for all parts. For example in this case you might simply implement the standard library [`clock()` function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) and define `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

If you *are* using two free-running cascaded timers, you must ensure high/low word consistency when combining the two counter values:

```
#include <time.h>

clock_t clock( void )
{
    uint16_t low_word = 0 ;
    uint16_t hi_word = 0 ;

    do
    {
        hi_word = readTimerH() ; 
        lo_word = readTimerL() ;

    } while( hi_word != readTimerH() ) ;

    return (clock_t)(hi_word << 16 | lo_word) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just looked into KL25 Sub-Family Reference Manual.
In Chapter 34 Real Time Clock (RTC) section 34.3.2 Time counter (may differ with document version).
I found that there are Two registers for Timer counter in RTC

1. 32-bit seconds counter
2. 16-bit prescaler register that increments once every 32.768 kHz clock cycle

---

Reference Manual says

**Always write to the prescaler register before writing to the seconds register,
because the seconds register increments on the falling edge of bit 14 of the prescaler
register.** 
Which means to calculate system time, read rtc_sec_counter and add 14 bits of prescalar_reg
you can even create a macro to give you system time in uSec and mSec from combination of rtc_sec_counter and prescalar_reg or Sec(obviously from rtc_sec_counter)

For 16 bit prescalar REG System clock is 32.768 Khz, with this we can create macros to get time in uSec and mSec

```
#define PRESCALAR_TICK 32768
#define KHZ            1000
#define MHZ            1000000

/// Here first we extract 14bit value of prescalar_reg and than multiply it with MHZ to get better precision 
/// but this value will not go more than 14 Bit
#define GET_SYS_US     ((((prescalar_reg & 0x03FFF)*MHZ)/PRESCALAR_TICK))
#define GET_SYS_MS     (GET_SYS_US)/KHZ)

if you need time in milliseconds up to 32 bit use below macro 
#define GET_SYS_US_32bit ((rtc_sec_counter * 0x3FFF) + GET_SYS_US)
#define GET_SYS_MS_32bit ((rtc_sec_counter * 0x3FFF) + GET_SYS_MS)
```

But to use these information you must initialise RTC of you micro (Obviously)

Comment: Sadly the development board comes with an 8 MHz quartz, but an external 32.x kHz quartz is required for the RTC. There is an internal 32k oscillator that could be used but that's probably not the solution. Good idea, otherwise.